# A problem in saving "long double" variables to hdf5 file

Tags: c++, hdf5, long-double

I'm new to `hdf5`. I'm trying to save the results of a simulation in `hdf5` file. The variables are `long double`. So, I mapped them into `NATIVE_LDOUBLE`. However, the saved values are completely wrong (fluctuating between very small and very large values).

When I save them with `NATIVE_DOUBLE`, everything is ok. But I need to save `long double`.

My question is how to properly save `long double` variables, and moreover `quadruple` precision variables?

I deeply appreciate your help. Examples are also appreciated.

here is the code

```cpp
 void createHDF5_2DProjectionFile(char* file_name, 
                                        CarGrid1D3V<long double>& ph_grid,
                                        std::string first_dim, 
                                        std::string second_dim,
                                        long double *x1, int size_x1, 
                                        long double *x2, int size_x2)
    {
        try
        {
            /* define the size  of the datasets containing the coordinates x1
            and x2    
            */

            PredType h5Int = PredType::NATIVE_INT;
            PredType h5DoubleL = PredType::NATIVE_LDOUBLE;
            PredType h5Double = PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE;        

            /* Define the parameters of grid space 
                DS --> Data Space
            */
            hsize_t x1_dims[1], x2_dims[1];
            x1_dims[0] = size_x1;
            x2_dims[0] = size_x2;
            
            
            H5File *file_id = new H5File(file_name, H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
            
            /* Saving string attribute
                Create dataspace with H5S_SCALAR
                Create string datatype of specific length of characters
                Create attribute and write to it
            */

            DataSpace attr_stringDS = DataSpace(H5S_SCALAR);
            StrType strdatatype(PredType::C_S1, 64);

            Attribute original_DistFun = file_id->createAttribute("/OriginalDistFun", 
                                                        strdatatype, attr_stringDS);
            original_DistFun.write(strdatatype, "1D3V");

            Attribute projection = file_id->createAttribute("/Projection", 
                                                        strdatatype, attr_stringDS);
            projection.write(strdatatype, first_dim + " - " + second_dim);


            /* Create the data spaces for grid points along each direction */
            DataSpace* first_dimDS_id = new DataSpace(1, x1_dims, NULL);
            DataSpace* second_dimDS_id = new DataSpace(1, x2_dims, NULL);
            
            /* Create and fille the datasets for grid points along each direction */
            DataSet *data_dim1 = new DataSet(file_id->createDataSet(first_dim, 
                                                h5DoubleL, *first_dimDS_id));

            data_dim1->write(x1, h5DoubleL);

            DataSet *data_dim2 = new DataSet(file_id->createDataSet(second_dim, 
                                                h5DoubleL, *second_dimDS_id));
            data_dim2->write(x2, h5DoubleL);
            
            /* Important attributes added to the file */
            long double x_minmax[2], px_minmax[2], 
                        py_minmax[2], pz_minmax[2], mom_steps[3],
                        ph_vols[3], spatial_steps[1];

            x_minmax[0] = ph_grid.x_min_;
            x_minmax[1] = ph_grid.x_max_;
            px_minmax[0] = ph_grid.px_min_;
            px_minmax[1] = ph_grid.px_max_;
            py_minmax[0] = ph_grid.py_min_;
            py_minmax[1] = ph_grid.py_max_;
            pz_minmax[0] = ph_grid.pz_min_;
            pz_minmax[1] = ph_grid.pz_max_;
            mom_steps[0] = ph_grid.dpx_;
            mom_steps[1] = ph_grid.dpy_;
            mom_steps[2] = ph_grid.dpz_;
            ph_vols[0] = ph_grid.dvs_;
            ph_vols[1] = ph_grid.dvp_;
            ph_vols[2] = ph_grid.dv_; 
            spatial_steps[0] = ph_grid.dx_;
            ph_grid.print_characteristics();
            std::cout << x_minmax[0] << " , " << x_minmax[1] << "\n";
            /* define attributes configuration */
            hsize_t space_1[1];
            space_1[0] = 1;

            hsize_t space_2[1];
            space_2[0] = 2; 
            
            hsize_t space_3[1];
            space_3[0] = 3; 
            
            DataSpace attr_space_1 = DataSpace(1, space_1);
            DataSpace attr_space_2 = DataSpace(1, space_2);
            DataSpace attr_space_3 = DataSpace(1, space_3);

            Attribute x_interval = file_id->createAttribute("[x_min,x_max]",
                                                        h5DoubleL, attr_space_2);
            x_interval.write(h5DoubleL, x_minmax);

            Attribute px_interval = file_id->createAttribute("[px_min,px_max]",
                                                        h5DoubleL, attr_space_2);
            px_interval.write(h5DoubleL, px_minmax);

            Attribute py_interval = file_id->createAttribute("[py_min,py_max]",
                                                        h5DoubleL, attr_space_2);
            py_interval.write(h5DoubleL, py_minmax);

            Attribute pz_interval = file_id->createAttribute("[pz_min,pz_max]",
                                                        h5DoubleL, attr_space_2);
            pz_interval.write(h5DoubleL, pz_minmax);

            Attribute MomVolumes = file_id->createAttribute("[dpx,dpy,dpz]", 
                                                            h5DoubleL, attr_space_3);
            MomVolumes.write(h5DoubleL, mom_steps);

            Attribute PhVolumes = file_id->createAttribute("[dv_s, dv_m, dv_t]",
                                                            h5DoubleL, attr_space_3);
            PhVolumes.write(h5DoubleL, ph_vols);

            Attribute SpatialVolumes = file_id->createAttribute("[dx]", PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE,
                                                                attr_space_1);
            SpatialVolumes.write(h5DoubleL, spatial_steps);

            /* Free memory */
            delete data_dim1;
            delete data_dim2;
            delete first_dimDS_id;
            delete second_dimDS_id;
            delete file_id;
        }
        catch(DataSetIException error)
        {
            error.printErrorStack();
        }
        catch(DataSpaceIException error)
        {
            error.printErrorStack();
        }
        catch(FileIException error)
        {
            error.printErrorStack();
        }     
    }
```

**Update**

A great discussion and explanations are available on HDF5 forum where I posted the same question
https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/a-problem-when-saving-native-ldouble-variables/9504

Also, [Steven Varga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1536326/steven-varga) provided examples to answer this question on his GitHub by constructing a user-defined datatype (see this [link](https://github.com/steven-varga/HDFGroup-mailinglist/tree/master/longdouble-custom-2022-03-15)).

Comment: the trouble with `long double` is that it maps to different formats in different compilers by default. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using g++. But I also have an intel compiler, so I can use it. I don't understand how exactly this mapping is performed. I expected that since it is defined as "PredType" in hdf5, I won't face any problem